# How do I get xarray.interp() to work in parallel?

Tags: dask, python-xarray

I'm using `xarray.interp` on a large 3D DataArray (weather data: lat, lon, time) to map the values (wind speed) to new values based on a discrete mapping function `f`.
The interpolation method seems to only utilise one core for computation, making the process horibly inefficient. I can not figure out how to make `xarray` to use more than one core for this task.

I did monitor the computation via `htop` and a `dask` dashboard for `xarray.interp`.
`htop` only shows one core to be in use, the dashboard doesn't show any activity in any of the workers. The only `dask` activity I can observe is from loading the `netcdf` data file from disk. If I preload the data using `.load()`, this `dask` activity is gone.

I also tried using using a `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` function with `xarray.apply_ufunc()` to achieve the equivalent result I am aiming for but did not observe any parallel utilisation (`htop`) or activity (`dask` dashboard) either.

The fastest approach for me right now is using `numpy.interp` and then recasting it back to a `xr.DataArray` with the coordinates of the original DataArray. But that's also not parallelised and only some percent faster.

In the following **MWE** I don't see any `dask` activity after the `da.load()` statement in block 4.

edit:
The code has to be run in the separate blocks 1 - 4 when evaluting using e.g. `htop`. Because `load()` is causing multi-core activity and happens either explicitly (block 2) or implicitly (triggered by 4), it's easy to missattribute the multi-core activity to `.interp()` when its caused by data loading if you run the script as a whole.

```py
# 1: For the dask dashboard
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client()
display(client)

import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

da = xr.tutorial.open_dataset("air_temperature", chunks={})['air']
```

```py
# 2: Preload data into memory
da.load()
```

```py
# 3: Dummy interpolation function
xp = np.linspace(0,400,21)
fp = -1*(xp-300)**2
xr_interp_da = xr.DataArray(fp, [('xp', xp)], name='interpolation function')
```

```py
# 4: I expect this to run in parallel but it does not
f = xr_interp_da.interp({'xp':da})
```

Comment: I ran that piece of code and I got activity in all the cores of my machine, with and without the `da.load()` statement.

Comment: Did you run the statements between each comment separatley or always as a whole @JulianGiles ? I didn't explicitly mention this (updated the question accordingly). If the script is run as a whole, the `.load()` also happens implicitly and also causes activity on my cores.
I don't see activity on more than one core in the last code block (no. 4), where I would expect more cores to participate.

Comment: I ran the code in separate blocks and also as a whole without the `.load()` statement and I got multi core activity. It's not continuous 100% activity in all cores but I definitively see several cores working at the same time while watching `htop`.